# Asymmetric confidence intervals on bootstrap estimates

Tags: variance, bootstrap, mean, python

I've performed bootstrapping on my leastsq parameters and now I have a load of data from which I can get the mean and standard deviation for each parameter. Lovely.

But when I look at a histogram of this data, I find (I suppose unsurprisingly) that the data is skewed [image: histogram]

(The line is the mean)

How do I report the clearly asymmetric variance and get the proper centre (in this ~0.75)?

Comment: You should do several checks before going any further. First, if this is a small dataset ("small" will depend on other characteristics, but less than a dozen or so points might qualify), then bootstrapping is unlikely to be reliable. Second, have you tested your bootstrapping code? How are you performing this bootstrap? (In a now-deleted question you mis-characterized the bootstrap, so I'm suspicious.) Third, there may be a few outlying values of the response and independent variables in influential positions (further making the bootstrap unreliable): have you checked for these?

Comment: This dataset consists of 58+ points and the fit depends on 5 parameters. The bootstrap is performed by randomly selecting, with replacement, 58 of these data points. And in this set, there doesn't appear to be any significant outliers.

I deleted the last question because I answered it during some research and implemented the bootstrap :)

Comment: Whether that is appropriate depends on how the independent variables are to be modeled. You are bootstrapping a random effects model rather than a fixed-effects model. With such a small data:variables ratio, it appears that many of the bootstrap samples may have high-leverage points and that there are in fact several extreme values of the response variable at those points. Although none of this is wrong, *per se,* these possibilities indicate the interpretation of the bootstrap results is subtle and complex.